# Mapwindow and XTools error: XSI is an undeclared namespace

Tags: shapefile, kml, kmz, mapwindow

I have tried MapWindow and XTools and have gotten this same error both times when trying to import a KML file into Shapefile format. Does anyone know how I can eliminate this error message?

"There was an error opening the KML file
'xsi' is an undeclared namespace. Line 3, position 34."